# Ubuntu upgrade 16.04 -> 17.04 stuck

Tags: apt, upgrade, keyboard, dpkg, 17.04

My upgrade is stuck on `Setting up keyboard-configuration`. I have seen the keyboard layout dialog which I answered successfully.

The faulty part seems to be the postinstall step `/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.postinst configure 1.108ubuntu15.3`. I have tried killing it. The upgrade process continued with more dependent steps failing. Had to kill the `openvpn` package configuration too.

[image: upgrade dialog]

Now I'm sitting with this upgrade dialog and don't really know what to do. Please help. I don't want to reboot my work machine just to find it unusable :(

Thanks for any effort or insight on how to debug it!

Comment: Updates to a STS version like 17.04 can only be done one after one, so this would be 16.04 → 16.10 → 17.04 here. As you encounter errors with multiple crucial packages, I suggest to make a clean install.

Comment: My original intention was to upgrade to 16.10 but the software updater offered me 17.04. Personal lesson learned - don't trust Ubuntu. Bad news for tomorrow standup meeting.

Comment: Not rebooting seems impossible.
If you want to try and repair your system (when a clean install seems more appropriate, as pointed by @dessert), the usual way to go would be to [boot in recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).
Then you will be able to access a root prompt and therefore install whatever package is broken.

Comment: A new installation of Ubuntu takes half an hour of time, let's make it one hour with copying files and personal settings – should be done until tomorrow, doesn't it?

Comment: Is it possible to keep my user settings and installed software when reinstalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone finds this useful, I debugged my `/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.postinst` and found out the `plymouth --ping` command was the problem. I had installed `ubuntu-gnome` and I suspect that had something to do with `plymouth` not working properly.

Anyway, I've edited the `postinst` script to skip the `plymouth` part and fall back to using `setupcon`. Then I ran `dpkg --configure -a` which completed successfully. Next, some cleanup:

`sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove`

Then Software Updater for some addditional updates.